# elfinder laravel 5 connector error

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, elfinder

I am trying to integrate barryvdh/laravel-elfinder package for ckeditor, elfinder window is opening but error says 'unable to connect to backend'. I checked the request/response in firebug and found this url with response 500

[http://testsite.dev/elfinder/connector?*token=SYqcfRYmhiU4tdrrD883ESd3CznYKLhnnCZnGO4O&cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&*=1428933143824](http://testsite.dev/elfinder/connector?_token=SYqcfRYmhiU4tdrrD883ESd3CznYKLhnnCZnGO4O&cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1428933143824)

i guess something is wrong with the connector config. I followed instructions from the github page with no luck. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm experiencing thiis problem on laravel 4. any ideas will be awesome

Comment: hi, please go through the conversation i had with barry, may be it will help

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/issues/52